# Gherkin 22.0.0 to 24.0.0 (Cucumber-gherkin 7.8.0)

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

I updatedmy pom.xml  and {cucumber.version} from 7.0.0 to 7.8.0

After update I found

> Gherkin.fromSources

has been removed in after gherkin (22.0.0) and in Gherkin 24.0.0 this function is missing

Similarly,

> makeSourceEnvelope(String data, String uri)

is also removed in same version. I am using TestSourcesModal.java to generate BDD report.

WHat are the replacemenet from these function in latest version. Can anyone help

I have looked at
https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/gherkin/latest/io/cucumber/gherkin/GherkinParser.Builder.html

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-gherkin

[image]

First error is

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method makeSourceEnvelope(String, String) is undefined for the type 
     TestSourcesModel
```

Second error is

```
Gherkin cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for Gherkin?

Comment: Yes I did, But didn't find anything relevant. https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-java/tree/main/src/test/java/io/cucumber/gherkin

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm

Comment: @MehulParmar Didn't tried recently but around my query time i reverted back to old version and never updated due to time constraint. Let me knw if you find any solution